# How do I exclude Weekend days in a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, weekend

How do I exclude values in a `DateTime` column that are Saturdays or Sundays?

For example, given the following data:

```
date_created
'2009-11-26 09:00:00'  -- Thursday
'2009-11-27 09:00:00'  -- Friday
'2009-11-28 09:00:00'  -- Saturday
'2009-11-29 09:00:00'  -- Sunday
'2009-11-30 09:00:00'  -- Monday
```

this is the result I'm looking for:

```
date_created
'2009-11-26 09:00:00'  -- Thursday
'2009-11-27 09:00:00'  -- Friday
'2009-11-30 09:00:00'  -- Monday
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 141, accepted):

When dealing with day-of-week calculations, it's important to take account of the current [`DATEFIRST`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) settings. This query will always correctly exclude weekend days, using [`@@DATEFIRST`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx) to account for any possible setting for the first day of the week.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, date_created) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT date_created
FROM your_table
WHERE DATENAME(dw, date_created) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

Comment: This might be problematic though. Run this script: `set language italian;
select DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '2015-01-01');` The result is `giovedì`.

Comment: Good point HuBeZa, for translating the day into another language I would run the following `SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages` and look for the language you wish to translate to

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, use DATEPART with dw:

```
SELECT date_created
FROM your_table
WHERE DATEPART(dw, date_created) NOT IN (1, 7);
```

**EDIT:** I should point out that the actual numeric value returned by DATEPART(dw) is determined by the value set by using SET DATEFIRST:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: It's possible to automatically handle any possible settings of `DATEFIRST`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 11):

Try the `DATENAME()` function:

```
select [date_created]
from table
where DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [date_created]) <> 'Saturday'
  and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [date_created]) <> 'Sunday'
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on your server's week-start set up, so it's either

```
SELECT [date_created] FROM table WHERE DATEPART(w,[date_created]) NOT IN (7,1)
```

if Sunday is the first day of the week for your server

or

```
SELECT [date_created] FROM table WHERE DATEPART(w,[date_created]) NOT IN (6,7)
```

if Monday is the first day of the week for your server

Comment if you've got any questions :-)

Comment: It's possible to automatically handle any possible settings of `DATEFIRST`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate Leave working days in a table column as a default value--updated

If you are using SQL here is the query which can help you: [http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Calculate...](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Calculate-Leave-working-501af27a/file/68664/1/02-Calculate%20Leave%20working%20days%20in%20a%20table%20column%20as%20a%20default%20value.sql)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
select (DATEDIFF(DD,'2014-08-01','2014-08-14')+1)- (DATEDIFF(WK,'2014-08-01','2014-08-14')* 2)
```