# How to find hours between 2 dates excluding weekends in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find hours between 2 dates excluding weekends. How to do it in MS SQL Server?

I have tried this,

```
CAST(( GETDATE() - [approval_date]) AS FLOAT) * 24.0 AS WorkedHours,
```

its including weekends.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count work days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Before posting the question I have tried all, Those answers give days, If I multiply with 24 Hours, will get Days*24, I am not getting exact Hours, in one day it may be 10 Hours also

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but it might help someone. This query returns the exact days, months and hours between two dates excluded All Sunday(s) and Saturday(s):

```
SELECT  (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @d1, @d2) -  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) * 2880) + 
CASE 
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) = 1 AND DATEDIFF(DW, @d1, @d2) <= 5 THEN 0 
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) = 0 THEN 0
ELSE 1440 END

SELECT (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @d1, @d2) - DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) * 48) + 
CASE 
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) = 1 AND DATEDIFF(DW, @d1, @d2) <= 5 THEN 0  
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) = 0 THEN 0
ELSE 24 END

SELECT (DATEDIFF(DW, @d1, @d2) - DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) * 2) + 
CASE 
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) = 1 AND DATEDIFF(DW, @d1, @d2) <= 5 THEN 0
    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @d1, @d2) = 0 THEN 0
ELSE 1 END
```

Or you can use this generic function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetBusinnessDaysTimeSpan]( 
 @DateFrom DATETIME,
 @DateTO DATETIME,
 @Type VARCHAR(50)
) 
RETURNS BIGINT
AS 
BEGIN 
        DECLARE @result AS BIGINT;
        IF @Type = 'Min'
        BEGIN
            SET @result = (SELECT  (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @DateFrom, @DateTO) -  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) * 2880) + 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) = 1 AND (DATEDIFF(DW, @DateFrom, @DateTO)) <= 5 THEN 0 
                                WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) = 0 THEN 0 
                            ELSE 1440 END
                            )
        END

        IF @Type = 'Hour'
        BEGIN
            SET @result = (SELECT (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @DateFrom, @DateTO) - DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) * 48) + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) = 1 AND (DATEDIFF(DW, @DateFrom, @DateTO)) <=5 THEN 0  
                    WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) = 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE 24 END
                )
        END

        IF @Type = 'Day'
        BEGIN
            SET @result = (SELECT (DATEDIFF(DW, @DateFrom, @DateTO) - DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) * 2) + 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) = 1 AND (DATEDIFF(DW, @DateFrom, @DateTO)) <=5 THEN 0  
                                WHEN  DATEDIFF(WK, @DateFrom, @DateTO) = 0 THEN 0 
                            ELSE 1 END
                            )
        END
        RETURN @result 
END
```

Comment: Just to let you know, I tried running that function with the following parameters and it does not return the expected result. Expected 12, actual 1


 DateFrom DATETIME ='2020-03-06 12:00:00'
 DateTO DATETIME = '2020-03-08 13:00:00'
 Type VARCHAR(50) = 'Hour'

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this was not as straight forward as I thought it was going to be.

I took [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-calculate-work-days-and-hours-in-sql-server/) blog/tutorial as a base and started working from there.

This is the scalar function I am now using. I did some smoke testing and it seems to work just fine. If you see any errors please let me know so I can test and update the solutio as necessary. I hope this helps others!

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWeekDayHoursDiff](@DateFrom datetime, @DateTo datetime)
RETURNS INT 

AS
BEGIN 

IF @DateFrom > @DateTo  
BEGIN
    return CAST('DateFrom cannot be lower thant DateTo parameters' as int);  -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZIpFytCSVc
END 

DECLARE @TotHours INT= DATEDIFF(Hour, @DateFrom, @DateTo);
DECLARE @TotWeekHours INT= DATEDIFF(WEEK, @DateFrom, @DateTo) * 48;
DECLARE @SundayOffset INT= CASE
                     WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateFrom) = 'Sunday' THEN  24 - DATEPART(HOUR, @DateFrom)
                     WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateFrom) = 'Saturday' THEN - (DATEPART(HOUR, @DateFrom))
                     ELSE 0
                  END;
DECLARE @SaturdayOffset INT= CASE
                       WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateTo) = 'Saturday' THEN - DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTo)
                       WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateTo) = 'Sunday' THEN  - DATEPART(HOUR, @DateTo) + 24
                       ELSE 0
                    END;


DECLARE @TotWorkingHours INT= @TotHours - @TotWeekHours - @SundayOffset + @SaturdayOffset;

   -- select @TotWorkingHours TotWorkingHours
      --   , @TotHours TotHours
         --, @TotWeekHours TotWWeekHours
         --, @SundayOffset SundayOffset
         --, @SaturdayOffset SaturdayOffset

RETURN @TotWorkingHours


END
```

Comment: This is the way. I tried some of the other solutions I found across SO and all failed with edge cases. This was the only one that passed all the tests I threw at it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
select datediff(hh, @d1, @d2)
```

where @d1 = date1
and @d2 = date2

In your case it would be like this

```
 select datediff(hh, GETDATE(), [approval_date])
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on [get DATEDIFF excluding weekends using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server), follow this query to get the hours

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HH, @date1, @date2) - (DATEDIFF(WK, @date1, @date2) * 2) -
       CASE WHEN datepart(DW, @d1) = 1 THEN 24 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN datepart(DW, @d2) = 1 THEN 24 ELSE 0 END
```