# RDLC Week Days report viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

I have the following expression in the report viewer report in visual studio:

```
=CDate(datetime.Today.AddDays(1)).Subtract(Fields!DateColumn.Value).Days
```

How can I get the Weekdays from the expression (Business days)?

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard... I ended up cretaing a SP using the solution from [get DATEDIFF excluding weekends using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server) and used it for the report.