# DateDiff Sql query excluding weekends as vairable using variable to create > X

Tags: php, sql, ms-access-2007

I have a bit of an issue, I've looked at other questions around this and notably seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server) similar issue.

However mine is that I'm writing a SQL query within PHP to pull data from an access database to display via the browser.

My query starts Select, a, b, c etc and then I get to the problem. One of my select criteria is

```
DATEDIFF('d',[Activity].[CreatedOn], NOW()) as Dif
```

Which works fine and pulls the number of days between created and now. However, if I add.

```
DATEDIFF('d',[Activity].[CreatedOn], NOW())- (DATEDIFF('wk', [Activity].[CreatedOn], NOW()) * 2) As Dif
```

Then the query returns nothing. In theory I should see the number of days minus number of weeks *2 to give me a rough idea of working days.

the second issue is trying to use my Dif variable to only show results where

```
Dif >= 7.
```

I assume this is due to how the actual value in the field is displayed as oppose to the output I have which is a numerical digit.

Appreciate any pointers where I'm going wrong with this.

FIXED second issue

```
AND (Activity.CreatedOn < NOW()-7)
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (Product specific question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateDiff parameter `interval` for **week** is `'ww'`, not `'wk'`.

Comment: arrrgh... Thanks, always the simple answer.