# SQL Server 2012: DateDiff excluding weekends in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, datediff

I have a dynamic SQL query which counts documents in a specific office which are signed more than 1 working day of their created date.

Here is the query:

```
set @strsql = '(select @cnt = COUNT(*) from '+@TableNameDocs+' D
                inner join dbo.Signatures S on D.id = S.TableId
                where S.cityid = '+str(@Cityid)+' and S.OfficeId = '+str(@Officeid)+' and S.isValid = 1 and D.cityid = '+str(@Cityid)+' and D.OfficeId = '+str(@Officeid)+' and DATEDIFF(day,D.CreatedDate,COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())) > 1)'
```

But I want to alter it so it counts only working dates with a check if the `office` is in a country where the weekend is Saturday and Sunday or in a country
where the weekend is Friday and Saturday. I can get the country of the office from the `Offices` table. The offices can be in Lebanon (Sat-Sun weekend) or in Saudi Arabia (Fri-Sat weekend)

Comment: This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server

Comment: @SureshPrajapati thank you but I have problem using this answer in the where clause using the needed if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this :
First find the `Country` of the `@Officeid` from `Offices` tables:

```
-- GET OFFICE'S COUNTRY
    SELECT @country = [Country] from dbo.Offices
    where officeid = @Officeid
```

Then depending on the country :

```
IF @country = 'SAUDI ARABIA' --Weekend in Saudi Arabia is Fri-Sat
    BEGIN
        set @strsql = '(select @cnt=COUNT(*) from '+@TableNameDocs+' D
                        inner join dbo.Signatures S on D.id = S.TableId
                        where S.cityid = '+str(@Cityid)+' and S.OfficeId = '+str(@Officeid)+' and S.isValid = 1 and D.cityid = '+str(@Cityid)+' and D.OfficeId = '+str(@Officeid)+' and 
                        ((DATEDIFF(dd, D.CreatedDate, COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())))
                        -(DATEDIFF(wk, D.CreatedDate, COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())) * 2)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, D.CreatedDate) = ''Saturday'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())) = ''Friday'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))>1)'

    END
    else
    BEGIN
        set @strsql = '(select @cnt=COUNT(*) from '+@TableNameDocs+' D
                        inner join dbo.Signatures S on D.id = S.TableId
                        where S.cityid = '+str(@Cityid)+' and S.OfficeId = '+str(@Officeid)+' and S.isValid = 1 and D.cityid = '+str(@Cityid)+' and D.OfficeId = '+str(@Officeid)+' and 
                            ((DATEDIFF(dd, D.CreatedDate, COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())))
                            -(DATEDIFF(wk, D.CreatedDate, COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())) * 2)
                            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, D.CreatedDate) = ''Sunday'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, COALESCE(S.SignedDate, GETDATE())) = ''Saturday'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))>1)'
    END
```

**credits**
[Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/calculatingworkdays/1660/)