# The difference between a certain date and today date is 200 excluding the weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a renewal date column and I would like my query to look at my renewal date on today's date and return a value (lets say `reminder_sent`) if their difference is 200 days. I want my query to exclude the weekends as well. Below what I roughly came up with. But I need help to get to my result. Could someone please help me with it.

```
dateiff(day,getdate(),convert(char(10),I.renew_date,101 )= 200
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get DATEDIFF excluding weekends using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server)

Comment: how can i set their difference to 200 days?

Comment: What do you mean by "set the difference"? Are you tehrefore asking how to *add* 200 working day to a date?

Comment: yes! You are totally correct! how do minus 200 working days from my renewal date? I want to be able to start following up on my renewal 200 days before my renewal days come? this is the request: "We would like to create a process that will send an email to the managers on an account that is 200 days from the renewal date"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add business days to date in SQL without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server)

Comment: @MahdiehReese seems like you are not accepting answers in your previous question ,  please go back your previous questions and accept them as answer those which helped you.

Comment: yes! this answered my question, Thanks