# Datetime difference excluding weekends in days, hh:mm:ss format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'm trying to get the difference between two datetime2 fields excluding weekends.

I was able to do it only for the date but struggling to include the time:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    start_datetime, end_datetime,
    cast(datediff(dd, start_datetime, end_datetime) - 
      (datediff(wk, start_datetime, end_datetime) * 2) -
      case when datepart(dw, start_datetime) = 1 then 1  else 0 end +
      case when datepart(dw, end_datetime) = 1 then 1  else 0 end
      as varchar(10)) as datediff_,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, right(start_datetime, 16), right(end_datetime, 16)) timediff_
  from mytable
)
SELECT *, datediff_ + ' days, ' +
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), timediff_/60/60)
  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), timediff_/60%60), 2)
  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), timediff_ % 60), 2) durationwoweekends
FROM cte;
```

This does calculate and return good when *timediff_* is positive, but when negative I get a bad output:

[image]

the output format of column *durationwoweekends* that I'm aiming at is *days, hh:mm:ss* now outputting a varchar which is prob wrong and also forcing string 'days,  ' but ultimately would need the field to be duration data type.

testing data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable(
start_datetime datetime2,
end_datetime datetime2
)
Insert into #temptable(start_datetime, end_datetime) values ('2022-10-31 10:30:52', '2022-11-02 23:47:55')
Insert into #temptable(start_datetime, end_datetime) values ('2022-11-01 08:30:46', '2022-11-03 02:59:27')

select * from #temptable
```

I'm using SQL Server 2019.
Any help from any one will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get DATEDIFF excluding weekends using sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388420/get-datediff-excluding-weekends-using-sql-server)

Comment: This has been answered so many times, it can almost have an own tag. Also, datepart(dw) is non-deterministic and is dependent on regional settings

Comment: @ThomA yes it does help for the number of days, but I'm missing the time in the output
struggle is really to get the output in x days, hh:mm:ss

Comment: One would assume you can determine how to change `DAY` to `HOUR`, @dmartins .

Comment: Would you ever need to deal with negative intervals? For example, 2022-11-02 back to 2022-10-31? You also need to make sure all of your edge cases are considered in your requirements and covered by your testing - (Fri-Sat, Fri-Sun, Fri-Mon, Sat-Sat, Sat-Sun, Sat-Mon, Sun-Sun, Sun-Mon) x (times earlier, same, or later) x (same weekend, different weekend).  **It is unusual to ignore days, but not ignore times.** What would the expected result be for an interval Saturday 16:00 to Sunday 08:00 or Sunday 16:00 to Monday 08:00?

Comment: An alternate algorithm that would have better consistency would be to treat all weekend start dates as equivalent to 00:00 Monday, and all weekend end dates as 24:00 Friday (00:00 Saturday).  If start and end are both on the same weekend, zero elapsed time is counted.  Essentially the elapsed time is consistently paused on weekends.

Comment: You need to borrow against days to get a positive result just like when subtracting numbers by hand. (It appears that your dates must both fall outside the weekend so apparently that doesn't complicate things.)

Answer (score 1):

It is unusual to ignore (or adjust for) weekend dates, but not adjust for times at the same time. That might lead to strange results for cases like:

1. "Saturday 1600" to "Sunday 08:00" being calculated as "0 days -8 hours".
2. "Saturday 0900" to "Monday 16:00" being calculated as a sorter interval than "Sunday 0800" to "Monday 16:00".

If ignoring weekend days, I believe you should ignore them in their entirety, including any time components. This can be done by mapping all datetimes from 00:00 Saturday through 24:00 Sunday as equivalent to 00:00 Monday. That would make the resulting calculations continuous and consistent. Effectively, the elapsed timer is paused from 00:00 Saturday through 24:00 Sunday (00:00 Monday).

As for calculating the date and time components for display, I would suggest:

1. Adjust the start and end datetimes, as described above, to map any weekend values to 00:00 Monday.
2. Calculate a single elapsed time value in seconds.
3. If negative, separate out the sign and continue with the absolute value.
4. Split the elapsed seconds into day and time components.
5. Adjust the day value to account for the skipped weekends.
6. Combine and format the results for display.

The following will accomplish this:

```
-- The weekday value from DATEPART(weekday) is locale/settings dependent
-- So we need to calculate the expected values
--   For @@DateFirst = 7, @SaturdayDW = 7 and @SundayDW = 1
--   For @@DateFirst = 1, @SaturdayDW = 6 and @SundayDW = 7
--   For @@DateFirst = 6, @SaturdayDW = 1 and  @SundayDW = 2
-- DATEDIFF(week, ...) is unaffected by the DateFirst setting.
DECLARE @SaturdayDW INT = DATEPART(weekday, '20000101') -- Reference Saturday
DECLARE @SundayDW INT = DATEPART(weekday, '20000102') -- Reference Sunday
--SELECT @@DateFirst AS DateFirst, @SaturdayDW AS SaturdayDW, @SundayDW SundayDW
  
SELECT
    T.TestSet, T.StartDateTime, T.EndDateTime,
    LEFT(DATENAME(dw, T.StartDateTime), 3) AS SDay,
    LEFT(DATENAME(dw, T.EndDateTime), 3) AS EDay,
    FMT.AdjustedStart,
    FMT.AdjustedEnd,
    FMT.Elapsed
FROM TestData T
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Adjust weekend dates forward to 00:00:00 of the following Monday
    SELECT
        CASE DATEPART(dw, T.StartDateTime)
            WHEN @SaturdayDW
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(day, 2, CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDateTime)))
            WHEN @SundayDW
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATE, T.StartDateTime)))
            ELSE T.StartDateTime
            END AS AdjStart,
        CASE DATEPART(dw, T.EndDateTime)
            WHEN @SaturdayDW
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(day, 2, CONVERT(DATE, T.EndDateTime)))
            WHEN @SundayDW
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATE, T.EndDateTime)))
            ELSE T.EndDateTime
            END AS AdjEnd
) ADJ
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Calculate raw differences
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(second, ADJ.AdjStart, ADJ.AdjEnd) AS Seconds,
        DATEDIFF(week, ADJ.AdjStart, ADJ.AdjEnd) AS Weeks
) DIFF1
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Calculate and adjust days, extract time-only component, handle negatives
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN DIFF1.Seconds < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END AS Sign,
        ABS(DIFF1.Seconds) / 86400 - 2 * ABS(DIFF1.Weeks) AS Days,
        DATEADD(second, ABS(DIFF1.Seconds) % 86400, 0) AS Time
) DIFF2
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Format intermediate data and results
    SELECT
       CONCAT(
           DIFF2.Sign,
           DIFF2.Days,
           CASE WHEN DIFF2.Days = 1 THEN ' Day, ' ELSE  ' Days, ' END,
           CONVERT(CHAR(8), DIFF2.Time, 108)
           ) AS Elapsed,
       CONCAT(
           LEFT(DATENAME(dw, ADJ.AdjStart), 3),
           ', ',
           CONVERT(CHAR(8), ADJ.AdjStart, 108)
           ) AS AdjustedStart,
       CONCAT(
           LEFT(DATENAME(dw, ADJ.AdjEnd), 3),
           ', ',
           CONVERT(CHAR(8), ADJ.AdjEnd, 108)
           ) AS AdjustedEnd
) FMT
ORDER BY T.TestSet, T.StartDateTime, T.EndDateTime
```

`CROSS APPLY`s are used above to conveniently encapsulate intermediate calculations, avoid duplication of subexpressions, and to reduce clutter in the final select list.

Care must be taken when working with `DATEPART(weekday, ...)` values, as the values returned are dependent on the `DATEFIRST` setting, which may default to either 1 or 7 depending on the locale. The logic above handles this by first calculating comparison weekday values for known Saturday and Sunday reference dates.

The `DATEDIFF(second, ...)` produces an integer result good for up to about 38 years. If longer intervals are needed, `DATEDIFF_BIG()` may be used.

Selected Results:

| Test Set | Start Date/Time | End Date/Time | SDay | EDay | Adjusted Start | Adjusted End | Elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-31 10:30:52 | 2022-10-31 10:30:52 | Mon | Mon | Mon, 10:30:52 | Mon, 10:30:52 | 0 Days, 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2022-10-31 10:30:52 | 2022-11-02 23:47:55 | Mon | Wed | Mon, 10:30:52 | Wed, 23:47:55 | 2 Days, 13:17:03 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 23:47:55 | 2022-10-31 10:30:52 | Wed | Mon | Wed, 23:47:55 | Mon, 10:30:52 | -2 Days, 13:17:03 |
|  | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 08:30:46 | 2022-11-03 02:59:27 | Tue | Thu | Tue, 08:30:46 | Thu, 02:59:27 | 1 Day, 18:28:41 |
| 2 | 2022-11-03 02:59:27 | 2022-11-01 08:30:46 | Thu | Tue | Thu, 02:59:27 | Tue, 08:30:46 | -1 Day, 18:28:41 |
|  | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 08:00:00 | 2023-12-01 16:45:00 | Fri | Fri | Fri, 08:00:00 | Fri, 16:45:00 | 0 Days, 08:45:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 08:00:00 | 2023-12-02 08:00:00 | Fri | Sat | Fri, 08:00:00 | Mon, 00:00:00 | 0 Days, 16:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 08:00:00 | 2023-12-03 16:45:00 | Fri | Sun | Fri, 08:00:00 | Mon, 00:00:00 | 0 Days, 16:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 08:00:00 | 2023-12-04 16:45:00 | Fri | Mon | Fri, 08:00:00 | Mon, 16:45:00 | 1 Day, 08:45:00 |
|  | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2023-12-02 08:00:00 | 2023-12-01 16:45:00 | Sat | Fri | Mon, 00:00:00 | Fri, 16:45:00 | -0 Days, 07:15:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-02 08:00:00 | 2023-12-03 16:45:00 | Sat | Sun | Mon, 00:00:00 | Mon, 00:00:00 | 0 Days, 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-02 08:00:00 | 2023-12-04 08:00:00 | Sat | Mon | Mon, 00:00:00 | Mon, 08:00:00 | 0 Days, 08:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-02 08:00:00 | 2023-12-04 16:45:00 | Sat | Mon | Mon, 00:00:00 | Mon, 16:45:00 | 0 Days, 16:45:00 |
| 3 | 2023-12-02 08:00:00 | 2023-12-31 23:59:59 | Sat | Sun | Mon, 00:00:00 | Mon, 00:00:00 | 20 Days, 00:00:00 |
|  | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 2023-12-01 10:00:05 | 2023-12-11 14:30:25 | Fri | Mon | Fri, 10:00:05 | Mon, 14:30:25 | 6 Days, 04:30:20 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ngvFAY0t) for a demo with a variety of test data.