# SQL - Add dates and exclude weekends

Tags: sql-server

I've read nearly every question and I must be overlooking something simple, but I cannot get this to calculate correctly for all scenarios. I have a date, and a reference table of different integers that I need to add to specific dates on each row. So for the sake of this question, I've just defined them specifically instead of a more complicated query.

For Date A, I need to add 7 days to the date, but exclude weekends.
For Date B, I need to add 5 days, but same as above, exclude weekends.

I've referenced the code from here,

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2008/10/01'
SET @EndDate = '2008/10/31'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

And applied it using my own logic to get this

```
SELECT '11/05/2015' AS [A Begin]
    , 7 AS [A Add]
    , CAST(DATEADD(day, ((DATEDIFF(wk, '11/05/2015', DATEADD(day, 7, '11/05/2015')) * 2) 
+ (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, '11/05/2015') = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, 7, '11/05/2015')) = 'Saturday' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + 7), '11/05/2015') AS DATETIME) 
+ CAST('16:00' AS DATETIME) AS [A End]
    , '11/05/2015' AS [B Begin]
    , 5 AS [B Add]
    , CAST(DATEADD(day, ((DATEDIFF(wk, '11/05/2015', DATEADD(day, 5, '11/05/2015')) * 2) 
+ (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, '11/05/2015') = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, 5, '11/05/2015')) = 'Saturday' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + 5), '11/05/2015') AS DATETIME) 
+ CAST('16:00' AS DATETIME) AS [B End]
```

For Range A, its adding 7 days, but lands on a Saturday as the End.. which I cannot have, it needs to equal 11/16/2015 to be correct. Range B works just fine. I am not able to perform Declares or any other functions.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1804095/3854195.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Morpheus Hah, very well could be server setting. MS 2005. I just got it to work I believe with another check to see if End Date is Saturday or Sunday, but It's likely the most messy thing I've ever written.

Comment: @Morpheus appears that datefirst only applies to 2008+. Something about always throwing in the white towel and asking on Stack Exchange forces me to answer my own question immediately after. I got it to work with using a case statement to fix any with the end date being Saturday or Sunday.. again messy, but it's working now.

Comment: Well, working is the key.  Messiness can always be addressed afterwards.  ;)