# Simulating NETWORKDAYS returns wrong business days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datediff

I created a NETWORKDAYS-like function on sql based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467132/sql-server-query-to-get-the-number-of-business-days-between-2-dates-excluding-h) which returns correctly the business days while the records (BEG and END) **are on business days**.

```
BEG        END         businessd
--------------------------------
01/01/2018 15/01/2018  10       

--(15 days total)-(1st jan)-(4 weekends) = 10 | correct result
```

But in some cases where BEG or END are "stored" in weekends it counts extra days:

```
BEG        END         businessd
--------------------------------
01/01/2018 28/01/2018  20       

--(28 days total)-(1st jan)-(4 weekends) = 19 | incorrect result
```

My code does a `datediff` between `BEG` and `FIN` and subtracting weekend days and the holydays stored on the `holydays` table

```
    SELECT e.*, 
            DATEDIFF(DAY, cast(BEG as datetime), cast(FIN as datetime))+1 --sum end date day
              -(SELECT
               (DATEDIFF(WK, cast(BEG as datetime), cast(FIN as datetime)) )
              +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, cast(BEG as datetime)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, cast(FIN as datetime)) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            ) * 2
            -(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holydays nl
             WHERE nl.FECHA BETWEEN cast(BEG as datetime) AND cast(FIN as datetime)
            ) AS businessd,

            convert(nvarchar(6),cast(BEG as datetime),112) as iddate --new id based on fin
    FROM e
    ORDER BY original_ini,BEG
```

How could I handle these cases to correctly count business days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use calendar table for this purpose. This operation will be very easy with it.

you can even handle bank holidays

[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202242/1118978) and [this (Calendar Table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql/5635628#5635628)

```
select * from calendar where isWorkDay = 1
```

will get you workdays and then you can make simple join like

```
select * from t
where exists 
( select 1 from calendar where isWorkDay = 1 and calendar.dt betweenn t.beg and t.end)
```

Comment: Hey sorry for answering so late, I created a table from scratch using your link but your JOIN doesn't seem to work. What do you call when you use `calendar.dt`?

Comment: you need to use `Calendar.CalendarDate`