# Get the values of all weekdays

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table with 7 rows having all weekdays as value. I just want a simple sql query to get all the values from the weekdays except weekends.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what does your database look like? How are the values stored? Strings, Integers, etc

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTableName] t
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,t.[YourDateField]) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DateField]) <> 'Saturday'
AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DateField]) <> 'Sunday'
```

There is a [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803987/how-do-i-exclude-weekend-days-in-a-sql-server-query) question with solutions.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL `WEEKDAY()` function returns the index of the day in a week for a given date (0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday through to 6 for Sunday).

Syntax: 
`WEEKDAY(date)` Where date is a date.

Comment: The question was for SQL Server not MySQL.