# Exclude weekend days in my where clause filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have the following query:

```
Use MyDatabase

select *
from Table1    
where [CreatedOn] between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
```

I need to filter by `[CreatedOn]` so that it excludes all Saturdays and Sundays between the specified dates.

What would be the correct syntax to perform this operation?

Comment: What have you researched? What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exclude Weekend days in a SQL Server query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803987/how-do-i-exclude-weekend-days-in-a-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Where [CreatedOn] between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
  and DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[CreatedOn]) not in (6, 7)
```

just be careful,  sunday is the first day of the week in some cultures. If that is the case you need to change `not in (6, 7)` to `not in (7, 1)`

you can check the first day of the week with `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`

Comment: When I run SELECT @@DATEFIRST, I get 7. So, I guess I will need to use "not in (7,1)".

Comment: @user3115933 `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, CreatedOn) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.