# Exclude row with date having day as Sunday & cell value is zero or null (in SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help with a T-SQL query.

How to exclude row with date having day as Sunday & cell value is zero or null in SQL Server.

Excluding Sunday is one condition with solutions like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803987/how-do-i-exclude-weekend-days-in-a-sql-server-query)

Now I need to apply a second condition - only to exclude Sundays if cell value is zero or null.

Comment: include an `AND` in your `WHERE`? Excluding the Sundays was the "hard part".

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **completely unsupported** (out of even extended support) by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is extremely vague and you should definitely consider reading these pages for the future:

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

However, here is an example which I *think* answers your question:

```
declare @sampleData table
(
    DateValue date,
    cell int
)

insert into @sampleData values
('2021-11-03',1),
('2021-11-04',2),
('2021-11-05',0),
('2021-11-06',4),
('2021-11-07',null),
('2021-11-08',0),
('2021-11-09',2),
('2021-11-10',2),
('2021-11-13',null),
('2021-11-13',0)

select *
from @sampleData
where datepart(dw,DateValue) <> 7
or isnull(cell,0) <> 0
```

This just excludes and Sundays where the "cell" column contains a zero or `NULL` value. As you can see, the Sunday 6th November is included as the cell value is 4 and the entries for 7th/8th November are included because while they have cell values of 0 and `NULL`, they are not Sundays. Only the entries for Sunday 13th November are excluded, because they are Sundays AND have a cell value of either 0 or `NULL`.